# Bootstrap radio button checked or active

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

hey here is my html + php (i have a class name $page)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" name="page_settings">
<div class="col-xs-12 style-mg-top-10">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="profilePrivacyRadios">Privacy: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">   
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary <?php echo ($page_settings['page_privacy'] == 1) ? 'active' : '' ; ?> ">
          <input type="radio" name="profilePrivacyRadios" id="option1" value="1"> on
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary <?php echo ($page_settings['page_privacy'] == 0) ? 'active' : '' ; ?> ">
          <input type="radio" name="profilePrivacyRadios" id="option2" value="0" > off
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>   
<div class="form-group">      
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="deathdayRadios"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">   
    <input class="btn button-stripes btn-default" type="submit" name="settings" value="submit" />
  </div>
</div>
```

with this form I am able to update settings and show what are the settings to the user, with a little bit of sql help.

i am sending data like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['settings'])) {
    $this->update_page_settings($_POST['profilePrivacyRadios');
}
```

}

and getting data like this:

```
$page_settings = $page->load_page_settings();
```

everything works fine if I choose an option. Even if I use bootstraps active and even if the right option looks selected, when I press submit without selecting anything I get, Undefined index: profilePrivacyRadios error. hence I have to press on even if it is on or I have to press off even if its off. How do I select the right button when I load the page?

Comment: dont you have a default selected on your radio buttons upon first load?

Comment: you tell me I post my code

Comment: if you dont have then just add an attribute checked on the radio, so its always set and you'll avoid undefined indeces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a test on your input fields as well. The input field must be given the attribute "checked":

```
<input type="radio" name="profilePrivacyRadios" id="option1" value="1" <?php echo ($page_settings['page_privacy'] == 1) ? 'checked' : '' ; ?> /> on
```

Answer (score 1):

You ca set any of the radio buttons as selected by default using `checked` attribute like

```
<input type="radio" name="profilePrivacyRadios" id="option1" value="1" checked="true">
```

or validate your form before submitting